# Avoid expanded focus of first DateTime apex:inputField

Tags: visualforce, inputfield

I have a Visualforce page that sets the focus to the first apex:inputField when the page is loaded.

Being a DateTime this expands out the calendar date picker control and obscures a number of other controls.

[image: DateTime as first inputField]

**How can I prevent the focus going on this control when the page if first loaded?**

Note, the Start Date apex:inputField isn't actually the first control on the page. The Media Type aspx:SelectList actually preceeds it, but for some reason doesn't get focus.

Comment: apply blur on first element using javascript. http://www.coding-issues.com/2016/03/remove-auto-focus-from-first-input-field-sales-force.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The focus appears to be set by a javascript method in `bodyOnLoad()`

[image: setFocusOnLoad]

By providing my own definition of this function I can prevent the focus being set to the DateTime inputField.

E.g. Add the following to your Visualforce page.

```
<script>function setFocusOnLoad(){ /*NOOP*/ }</script>
```

While this works I'm open to a better solution. Salesforce could easily break this in the future by changing the function name etc...

Comment: An easier fix is to place the date field elsewhere on the page so it is not the first element. The first element should be a text field (e.g. a number input, text input, phone input, etc). A good candidate is the name field, if not set to auto-number, or some other text field otherwise. This also applies to standard page layouts, not just Visualforce, and should be forward compatible.

Comment: Mark this as the Accepted Solution -- it's simple simple awesome

Comment: You should be careful with this solution as it doesn't always work. The reason is because the sfdcPage.executeOnloadQueue statement could call the setFocus method, which will set focus to the first field in the form, and if that is a date field, then you will see the datepicker control despite having redefined the setFocusOnLoad method. I have used: function setFocus() { } with better success

Comment: @SeanRussell Yes, this is going to be the downside to this style of solution. It might break as Salesforce make changes or how the page is composed. Thanks for the suggestion to use setFocus().

Comment: function setFocus() { } worked for me! Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem to be a documented feature, but the `setFocus` function called by Visualforce upon page load will skip fields where the `data-skipFocus` attribute is `"true"`.

So possible solutions include setting this attribute on `apex:inputField`:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!record.Start_Date__c}" html-data-skipFocus="true" />
```

or on all of the fields before the onload event fires, e.g.

```
var form = document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm}');
[].forEach.call(form.elements, function(el) {
  if (el.type === 'text' || el.type === 'textarea') {
    el.setAttribute('data-skipFocus', 'true');
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!